# How do I change the review ratings from S's in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I change the image of the review ratings in WooCommerce from the current 'S' to actual star images? 
After a good Google search, i've tried this: [Replace theme ratings with WooCommerce stars](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203103677-Replace-theme-ratings-with-WooCommerce-stars)
But it doesn't work. It just changes the S's to small boxes.

Current CSS:

```
.woocommerce .star-rating {
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:1em;
    line-height:1;
    font-size:1em;
    width:5.4em;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue Light;
}
.woocommerce .star-rating:before {
    content:"\73\73\73\73\73";
    color:#d3ced2;
    float:left;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.woocommerce .star-rating span {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:1.5em;
}
.woocommerce .star-rating span:before {
    content:"\53\53\53\53\53";
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this in your CSS:

```
.woocommerce .star-rating span {
   font-family:star;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54668857/star-rating-for-woocommerce-not-showing-on-chrome) helped me.

I added to `style.css` of my child theme the next code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'star';
    src: url('../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.eot');
    src: url('../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.svg#star') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Full paths to let you understand better what's going on:

**Add code here:** `/wp-content/themes/gon-child/style.css`

**Original place where fonts live:** `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/`

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a css overwriting the item's font style.
Sample code that causes this:

```
*{
    font-family:'Raleway' !important;
}
```

Click on the browser's dev tools item, and look for styles defined below it that may be reaching it, and disable it and you'll see that the stars will load

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Nginx** (or **docker** with nginx service), don't forget to add the permissions for font files to **nginx.conf**

```
# Static files
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|svg|html|txt|eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    access_log        off;
    add_header        Vary Accept-Encoding;
    expires           30d;
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer for the question

Comment: This in not answer for question