# Woocommerce star rating bug

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make a woocommerce theme, but the star ratings aren't working properly.

This is the code for showing the star rating.

```
<div class="rating-custom">
  <?php wc_get_template( 'single-product/rating.php' ); ?>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.woocommerce-product-rating {
  margin-bottom: 1.618em;
  line-height: 2;
}
.woocommerce-product-rating .star-rating {
  margin: 0.5em 4px 0 0;
  float: left;
  font-family: star;
}
.woocommerce-product-rating::after, .woocommerce-product-rating .rating-custom, .woocommerce-product-rating::before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.star-rating {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 5.4em;
  font-family: star;
}
.star-rating::before {
  content: "SSSSS";
  color: #d3ced2;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.star-rating span {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}
.star-rating span::before {
  content: "SSSSS";
  top: 0;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

But my result is only "$$$"

[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RUa9.png)

Can someone help me on how to  make this work the way i want?

Comment: Your `font-family` doesn't appear to be coming through. Have you referenced the font correctly?

Comment: Check this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428079/how-do-i-change-the-review-ratings-from-ss-in-woocommerce/

Answer (score 0):

Following [Obsidian Age](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341603/obsidian-age) answer, i've added this line of code to my span tag: `font-family: 'star'`

And now everything is running smooth. Ty to [zipkundan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5634314/zipkundan) aswell for the help!