# star rating for woocommerce not showing on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, woocommerce

I'm using wordpress woocommerce, and is this file  woocommerce/assets/css/_fonts.scss it has this code.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'star';
    src: url('../fonts/star.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/star.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/star.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/star.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/star.svg#star') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'WooCommerce';
    src: url('../fonts/WooCommerce.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/WooCommerce.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/WooCommerce.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/WooCommerce.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/WooCommerce.svg#WooCommerce') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

the HTML looks like this

```
<div class="star-rating">
   <span style="width:100%">Rated 
   <strong class="rating">5.00</strong> out of 5</span>
</div>
```

I have all the font files too. It works fine on Firefox, but on chrome is shows some weird chars? Any idea how to fix this?

[font css here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/css/_fonts.scss)

**UPDATE:**

I noticed these errors on chrome

**Access to font at 'https://bla.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.woff' from origin 'https:MY_URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
(index):571 GET https://bla.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.woff net::ERR_FAILED
(index):1 Access to font at 'https://bla.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.ttf' from origin 'https:MY_URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
(index):657 GET https://bla.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.ttf net::ERR_FAILED**

Answer (score 1):

Got it work, i disabled CORS headers on `stackpathcdn` and I converted woff to woff2 and changed the css to this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'star';
    src: url('../fonts/star.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/star.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/star.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/star.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/star.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/star.svg#star') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'WooCommerce';
    src: url('../fonts/WooCommerce.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/WooCommerce.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/WooCommerce.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/WooCommerce.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/WooCommerce.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/WooCommerce.svg#WooCommerce') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to convert your fonts to woff2 in my case it worked, apparently chrome can have problems with diffrent formats/

Comment: converted and added these `url('../fonts/star.woff2') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/star.woff') format('woff'),` and `url('../fonts/WooCommerce.woff2') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/WooCommerce.woff') format('woff'),`  but still same results. cleared cache too